# Bluetooth Low Energy - Smart vs Smart Ready device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

After going through this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy#Bluetooth_Smart_branding) on BLE, I understood that BLE ***SmartReady*** devices are dual mode devices (BT as well as BLE) whereas ***Smart*** devices are single mode devices (only BLE).

Few of my friends say that SmartReady device is a Master whereas Smart device is just a slave. Other say that, 'Though the role of master/slave can be switched at any point of time, all slaves share the master's clock.'

Could you please clarify which is true?

Answer (score 1):

A Smart device can be a master **or** a slave. It is important to understand that when a Smart device communicates with a SmartReady device, they're both using the 'low energy' subset of Bluetooth v4.0, and therefore either can be master or a slave, depending on your implementation.

Generally, being Smart or SmartReady is a hardware feature, while being master or slave is a connection feature, so the two are not related.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can say with certainty that your first statement is true and your friends' statements are false.

In RF there is no clock sharing. Smart/SmartReady do not imply Master/Slave/Client/Server roles.